# Create key in a array without using foreach?

Tags: php, arrays

Sometime I need to create key in a array if it don't exist.

For example:

```
$dataAgent['Paul'] = array('Sale' => 4,'Conv' => 1.5);
$dataAgent['Bill'] = array('Sale' => 6,'Conv' => 5.5);
$dataAgent['Tom'] = array('Sale' => 1);
$dataAgent['Jake'] = array('Sale' => 6,'Conv' => 10.5);
```

`'Conv'` key is missing in `$dataAgent['Tom']` array.

I use the following code to check if '`Conv'` key exist:

```
foreach($dataAgent as &$agent) { 
  if (!isset($agent['Conv'])) { 
     $agent['Conv'] = 0; 
  }  
}
```

Is there alternative way instead of using foreach and better readability?

Comment: use array_key_exists() to check key exists

Comment: `array_key_exists` is unnecessary. `isset` does the work fine.

Answer (score 2):

You will *have* to loop through the array one way or another, the key is not going to magically appear in all elements at once. You can just dress up the operation differently. My favourite would probably be:

```
$dataAgent = array_map(function (array $data) { return $data + array('Conv' => 0); }, $dataAgent);
```

Note that the `+` operator makes the use of `isset` unnecessary here.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the solutions:

1. Put this key while forming your array. OR
2. Use array_walk($Your_array, "your_function");

   ```
    function your_function($value, $key)
    {
    // put your logic here.
    }
   ```

for more info: https://www.php.net/array_walk